# VB .NET application re architecturing

Tags: vb.net, oop, uml, ooad

I got to re-architect existing VB.NET application, current application is not developed considering Object Oriented Approach. so Customer find difficulty in maintaining it.

Is there any tool to get the Class diagram from VB.NET source code? In JAVA I used to do it with free tools like ObjectAid etc.

How to create Design which will be maintainable and robust.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on a project in Visual Studio and choose 'View Class Diagram'.

I find this useful for relatively small projects, but larger ones are a little too cumbersome. Depending how your project is currently setup then the information might not be all that useful, but it is worth checking out.

I have had success with these class diagrams before, however on our main VB.NET project that isn't OO based (it uses datasets and SQL stored procedures mainly), the class diagram was so messy it wasn't much help!